# When the TrafficStats tx and rx values gets reset?

Tags: android

My application uses TrafficStats class to read tx and rx of every application. I am checking tx and rx value periodically. what i had observe is these values resets when device reboots or user switch from 3g to wifi. My question is, apart from these activities, when does tx and rx values gets reset and what is the maximum range of the tx, rx value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tx` and `rx` values are returned in `long` (4bytes). Therefore, for `unsigned long`, the max would be `2^32`. I believe the counter will also reset when is is overflowed.

Comment: Errr.. just found out that java doesn't have the unsigned data type.. So the max value of the counter would be 2147483647? Anyone can answer this?

Comment: OK, finally.. Max range of tx and rx will be 2^64. You'll need to use Long instead of long.